# Unable to locate element in the popup

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate those buttons as shown here:

[image]

And this is HTML for the same :

[image]

I tried with all possible ways but nothing works.

Comment: Please post the HTML code :)

Comment: What have you tried? Post all your code

Comment: Please post error you facing and the code what did you tried so far as well

Comment: can you add you full html code?

Comment: what do you mean with "I tried with all possible ways"? Please share the code you've tried to achieve what you want

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared you can locate the **`Continue with New`** button with either the following options :

- **`XPATH`**

  ```
  //button[@class='slm-btn slm-btn-AdvanceFlow' and @id='Continue']/span[@class='slm-btn-text']
  ```
- **`CSS_SELECTOR`**

  ```
  button.slm-btn.slm-btn-AdvanceFlow#Continue > span.slm-btn-text
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to try with id because it is the best way to get it because it is unique.

Otherwise, you can use XPath:

```
//button[@id='ContinueNew']
//button[contains(@id,'ContinueNew')]
```